# Views removed/added in layout are not properly redrawn

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

I'm trying to remove and add views during onLayout in a ViewGroup, but this causes some child views not to properly redraw.

Consider the following view:

```
public static class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

  View view;

  int count;

  boolean removeInLayout = true;

  public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myview, this, false);
    addView(view);
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        count++;
        requestLayout();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (removeInLayout) {
      removeViewInLayout(view);
    }

    invalidate();

    final String text = "Count: " + count;
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.one)).setText(text);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.two)).setText(text);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.three)).setText(text);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.four)).setText(text);

    if (removeInLayout) {
      LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
      addViewInLayout(view, 0, lp);
      final int wms = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
      final int hms = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lp.height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
      view.measure(wms, hms);
    }

    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
  }

  @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
        MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));

    measureChild(view, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
}
```

With the following xml layout as a child:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/one"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="84dp"
      android:background="#FF00FF00"
      tools:text="First View"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/four"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingBottom="2dp"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:text="Second View"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-light"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Third View"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/four"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
      tools:text="Fourth view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Initially the view and its children draw just fine, and on the first click every view is redrawn as well. Any further clicks will only cause the views with id "one" and "four" to be redrawn. "two" and "three" becomes stuck.
If I remove the `invalidate()` from onLayout the views are never redrawn.

If I swap out the `removeViewInLayout` and `addViewInLayout` with `detachViewFromParent` and `attachViewToParent` the views are properly redrawn. If I remove the invalidate they are never redrawn.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening? Should it not be possible to remove and re-add a view during the layout phase? And why isn't the fact that the child view is invalidated, although while detached, enough to cause a redraw?

I have uploaded a sample app to https://github.com/SimonVT/add-in-layout - click anywhere on the screen to fire the OnClickListener which increments the count variable and requests a layout.